# Zebra QLn220, print barcode using Android

Tags: android, printing, zebra-printers

I have no idea how to solve the problem so if someone succeeded to print an barcode with the QLn220 and can share the code, it should help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zebra provides and SDK with developer demos showing how to print on a QLn

http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

Link OS multiplatform sdk says only these devices are compatible

Samsung Galaxy Rugby (2.3.6)
Samsung Galaxy Nexus (4.0.4)
Motorola ET-1 (2.3.4)
Motorola MC40
Nexus 4 (4.2)
Nexus 7 (4.2)
Nexus 10 (4.2)
Honeywell Dolphin® 7800

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/link-os-sdk.html
Go to "Detailed Specs" tab